# How tensorflow graph regularization (NSL) affects triplet semihard loss (TFA)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nsl

I want to train a binary target deep neural network model using `nsl.keras.GraphRegularization` as described in this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/neural_structured_learning/tutorials/graph_keras_lstm_imdb#create_graph-regularized_model). My model has a [triplet semihard loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/TripletSemiHardLoss#class_tripletsemihardloss) in an intermediate dense layer which should not be "graph regularized".

From the `nsl.keras.GraphRegularization` [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/neural-structured-learning/blob/v1.1.0/neural_structured_learning/keras/graph_regularization.py#L87-L91) on Github:

> Incorporates graph regularization into the loss of `base_model`.
>
> Graph regularization is done on the logits layer and only during training.

It means that the intermediate triplet semihard loss will not be affected by this regularization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's right. Graph regularization will only be applied on the outputs of `base_model`. If your `base_model` uses triplet semihard loss in another layer, that loss should remain unaffected and preserved. If that's the not the case, please file a bug at https://github.com/tensorflow/neural-structured-learning/issues.